# Android Intent didn't start automatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm creating an application for android that implement BaseAdapter for gridView and TabFragment to create a sweepable application. The problem is when I click the object in grid, the Intent doesn't start automatically. I must swipe screen to other Fragment, then back to Fragment before to start Intent. Did anyone know about this problem? This is my sample code from gridAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    final PdfViewer pdf = new PdfViewer();
    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageButton(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageButton) convertView;
    }
    Bitmap image = decodeFile(_imgPaths.get(position), imageWidth, imageHeight);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
    return imageView;
}
class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    int _postion;
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        File file = new File(_filePaths.get(_postion));
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        _activity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `_activity`? and your adapter constructor?

Comment: _activity from FragmentActivity, and I used BaseAdapter for my view constructor

Comment: It's okay now, but the problem change. My intent need long time to start, roughly almost 2 minutes for first time. But its fast for second time and later, as long as the application still running. Is it because of my code or my hardware specification?

Comment: For sure your code. Normal apps don't need that long to start up, even on dog-slow cheap phones.